# Please explain how this digraph is Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Please explain how this diagram is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

[image: Diagram HERE!]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the diagram is saying each element is only related to itself, so $R= \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$. This is clearly a *reflexive* relation. So let's look at the other two properties.

1. A Relation is *symmetric* if $(a,b) \in R$ implies $(b,a) \in R$.
2. A Relation is *transitive* if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ implies $(a,c)\in R$.

Note that (1) is true since each relation looks like $(x,x)$ and in addition to $(x,x)$, the relation $(x,x)$ with the two $x$'s switched is in $R$. Note also that (2) is true because anytime we have two relations whose first and second coordinate overlap, like $(\_,b)$ and $(b,\_)$ they are the relation $(x,x)$, which then only requires $(x,x)$ to be in $R$. It is, so we're good.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you have time, please can you elaborate more on the transitivity? I understand (a,b) and (b,c) then (a,c) but I don't see that relationship in (_,b) and (b,_). :( Help me unlock my brain on this.

Comment: @Sanone no. You should form a specific question. What is unclear to you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you have time, please can you elaborate more on the transitivity? I understand (a,b) and (b,c) then (a,c) but I don't see that relationship in (,b) and (b,). :( Help me unlock my brain on this

Comment: @Sanone the hypothesis of transitivity is only met if you have two pairs in your relation where the second part of one is the first part of the other, like $(\_,b)$ and $(b,\_)$. Think a bit more how to better word your question next time.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Actually I pressed the ENTER key to move to a new line but it triggered the "Add Comment" button event.